# django-constance not setting up database backend

Tags: django, django-constance

I'm trying to add `django-constance` to an existing Django 3.2.9 project and am completely unable to get the database backend to set up.

I've added `constance` to `INSTALLED_APPS` before my apps, as the docs state.

```
In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: 'constance' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
Out[2]: True
```

I've specified the backend and limited to one of the two dbs the project is using:

```
CONSTANCE_BACKEND = 'constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'
CONSTANCE_DBS = ['default']
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {'TESTVAR': ('testing constance', 'This is a test field only')}
```

However, *no* migration happens:

```
# ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, adminactions, api, audit, auscert_website, auth, axes, contenttypes, db, failure, flatpages, images, lock, malurlfeed, members, notifications, oldnodes, otp_static, otp_totp, ourforms, redirects, reversion, sessions, sites, two_factor
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

And I'm then unable to change the value of `TESTVAR`:

```
# ./manage.py constance list
TESTVAR
# ./manage.py constance set TESTVAR test
# ./manage.py constance get TESTVAR

#
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I've scoured the docs and the repo's issues and am at a loss for how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added an extra line to INSTALLED_APPS in Django settings.py, manually adding the App corresponding to the database backend to fix this problem.
Like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'constance',
    'constance.backends.database',
]
```